# Set header/footer from cell value AND set font to barcode

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, header, footer

I need a barcode to generate in the header or footer that is based on a number value in cell B5. This value will vary. I can get the cell value to populate or the barcode font to show with a set value but can't get it to do both. Please help and suggestions are appreciated.

```
Sub barcode() 
    ' this one works for the value

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterHeader = Range("B5").Value    
    End With
End Sub



Sub test() ' this one works great for the font
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "&""IDAutomationHC39M Free Version,Regular""rw"
     End With
End Sub



Sub test2() ''Trying to put them together though just clears the header completely 
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "&""IDAutomationHC39M Free Version,Regular" & Range("B5").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that font but when I tried to set up my header with

```
.CenterHeader = "&""Arial" & Range("B5").Value
```

it cleared the header - i.e. reproduced your problem.
Experimentation led me to

```
.CenterHeader = "&""Arial""&14" & Range("B5").Value
```

In other words - you need to give it a size as well as the font name (and text)

Comment: So I Tried it exactly like yours and also edited the font name no luck just clears the header

Comment: `Sub test()

 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
 .CenterHeader = "&""IDAutomationHC39M Free Version,Regular""&14" & Range("B5").Value
 End With

End Sub`

Comment: `Sub test2()

 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "&""Arial,""&14" & Range("B5").Value
 End With

End Sub`

Comment: Still, only this one works to show the font once I add the cell reference it will clear the header .  `Sub test()

 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
 .CenterHeader = "&""IDAutomationHC39M Free Version,Regular""&14""rw"
 End With

End Sub`

Comment: Do I need to set it as a variant or something? Like                                                        
            `Dim ID As Variant `   `Set ID= Range("B5")`                                                                                        I have tried to work that in with no success also.

Comment: My code worked for me so I can only assume it is the font  name that is the issue "IDAutomationHC39M Free Version,Regular". I've never seen a comma in a font name before - the FontsGeek website claims the name is "IDAutomationHC39M Free Version Regular" - i.e. without the comma. Try that